# Oracle Apex: How to test if text field entry is already in database?

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I've built a form containing text fields. In one of the texts fields, the user is supposed to type in an e-mail address (other fields are for first name, last name etc. … with the data records I want to built up subscriptions for an e-mail newsletter that shows weekly developments in quality assurance data).

Is there a possibility to test right after the e-mail text field is filled if the respective e-mail address is already existent in the database? I've tried different methods but have problems with getting the text field text into my query-code (tried to write it to a hidden item via javascript $s, submit it via d.a. on change and take it from there - no success either). This is the code I want to use to check for the mentioned condition (P12_CHOICE is a radio button and subscription_a/_b are the tables that hold the subscription data - I had to make a differentiation here because there a two "styles" of the newsletter an user can choose from ):

```
v_count NUMBER:=0;

BEGIN

IF :P12_CHOICE = 1 THEN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM subscription_a WHERE TRIM(LOWER(EMAIL)) =                                                      
  TRIM(LOWER(''||V('P12_HIDDEN_ITEM')||'')); 

    IF v_count > 0 THEN
      return true;
    ELSE 
      return false;
    END IF;

ELSIF :P12_CHOICE = 2 THEN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM subscription_b WHERE TRIM(LOWER(EMAIL)) =                   
  TRIM(LOWER(''||V('P12_HIDDEN_ITEM')||''));

    IF v_count > 0 THEN
      return true;
    ELSE 
      return false;
    END IF;

END IF;

END;
```

I don't know if it is a session state issue (don't think so because I can see the hidden item's value in apex "session") or what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a similar example. It's a form on the EMP table with a check to ensure a record for that ENAME doesn't exist yet.

Add a dynamic action on change of page item P152_NAME

- True Action of type Execute Server-side Code:

```
DECLARE
  l_exists NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 INTO l_exists FROM EMP WHERE upper(ENAME) = :P152_ENAME;
  :P152_ENAME_EXISTS := 'Y';  
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  :P152_ENAME_EXISTS := 'N';
END;
```

Items to submit: `P152_ENAME`,Items to return: `P152_ENAME_EXISTS`

- True Action of type "Alert" with client condition "Item=Value" (Item: P152_ENAME_EXISTS, Value Y)

This works just fine. When I enter KING I get the alert. When I enter KOEN it passes.

Side note on your code:

- maybe you could store all values in the "email" columns as trimmed and lower. That way you don't have to perform any functions on that column in selects and indexes can be used.
- I'd avoid patterns like `IF :P12_CHOICE = 2`. Remember that page items come from the browser and everything is a string in a browser so you're assuming oracle is doing the conversion for you. To be safe I'd do `IF :P12_CHOICE = '2'`

Comment: Thank you! This works when I substitute :P152_NAME (using your example) with a string like 'abc@mail.com'. I'm getting the correct result whether the E-Mail abc@mail.com already exists in the DB-table. When I try to put the item value into the my pl/sql code, it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong concerning escaping the qoutes that identify the string? I want to come up  with: SELECT 1 INTO l_exists FROM subscription_a WHERE MAIL = 'abc@mail.com';

Comment: My bad... I didn't submit and return the text field/value properly... it works fine now ;-)