# How to read Apex 21.2 CheckboxGroup values in PL/SQL

Tags: checkbox, plsql, oracle-apex

I'm using Apex 21.2 on a 21.C database.  I can't read the values that the user has checked when I execute a PL/SQL dynamic action.
The Checkbox Group field is called `P302_MINISTRY_GROUP`.
The Type = `Checkbox Group`.
The LOV SQL Query = `Select ministry || ' - ' || role display, prim_key return from vol_ministry order by ministry, role;`
I did not put anything into the Source, Default, or Server Side Conditions.
I created a dynamic action that fires when the user presses the "Save" button.
For the TRUE Action = `Execute Server-side Code`.
The PL/SQL code is:

```
declare
  l_dummy number;
  l_volunteer_pk number;
begin
  l_volunteer_pk := :P302_PRIM_KEY;
  for cur_r in (select * From table(apex_string.split(:P302_MINISTRY_GROUP, ':'))) 
  loop
    select prim_key
      into l_dummy
      from vol_contact_ministry where ministry_fkey = cur_r.column_value
                                  and contact_fkey = l_volunteer_pk;
    if l_dummy is null then
       -- checked value does not exist
       insert into vol_contact_ministry (ministry_fkey, contact_fkey, status) 
                                 values (cur_r.column_value, l_volunteer_pk, 'Active');
    --else
       -- checked value exists
    --   delete from vol_contact_ministry where ministry_fkey = cur_r.column_value
    --                                      and contact_fkey = l_volunteer_pk;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
```

The checkboxes display on the screen with the concatenated fields just fine.  When the user checks one or more boxes and presses "Save", I would expect that the PL/SQL would loop through the checked boxes and give the prim_key associated with that box.  But I can't seem to get any values at all.  As a test I tried inserting the entire field :P302_MINISTRY_GROUP but the table shows Null for that insert.  The PL/SQL is firing properly when the button is pressed based on other tests that I made, but I can't get this code above to work.  How do I obtain the values of checked boxes from a Checkbox Group so that I can manipulate it in PL/SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you creating a dynamic action for this ? The logical (traditional) way of doing this is to submit the page and create a page process with the code you have posted. That should just work.

You can do it with a dynamic action (but that is probably overhead). I suspect  that you have not put `P302_PRIM_KEY, P302_MINISTRY_GROUP` in the attribute "Items to Submit" of the action of type "Execute Server-side Code".

The "Items to Submit" attribute ensures that values that are on the screen but not in the database session are sent to the database so they can be picked up by the code you're running.

Here is an example (from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76101217/oracle-apex-how-to-test-if-text-field-entry-is-already-in-database/76101384#76101384) )

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding Koen.  You're absolutely right.  I didn't have those page items in the "Items To Submit" field.  I also adjusted the PL/SQL.